# Access anonymous enumerated value with dot

Tags: c++

This code compiles (and appears to work) with both GCC and Clang:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    enum { number = 42 };
};

int main()
{
    Foo bar;
    std::cout << bar.number << std::endl;
}
```

[See it here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac01bf0cbac65514)

It was surprising to me that the compiler accepts `bar.number`; all text books I can find teach to use `Foo::number` to access the enumerated value.

Is this code valid? Note that GCC gives a weird warning ("variable 'bar' set but not used"), while Clang doesn't complain about it.

Comment: Works without warnings in VC++, too.  Curious to see what those who love reading the C++ standard say about it.  I've never bothered to question it :-)

Comment: Looks like a nice feature, you can change from const int to enum if you like, and it should still compile.

Comment: @marcin_j: Well, no, only do that if your constants represent enumerations. Otherwise you're abusing the feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's perfectly valid:

> `[C++11: 7.2/10]:` Each *enum-name* and **each unscoped enumerator is declared in the scope that immediately contains the *enum-specifier***. Each scoped enumerator is declared in the scope of the enumeration. These names obey the scope rules defined for all names in (3.3) and (3.4). *[..]* **An enumerator declared in class scope can be referred to using the class member access operators (`::`, `.` (dot) and `->` (arrow))**, see 5.2.5.

The same text (minus rules for scoped enums) can be found in the C++03 standard, at the same location.

I have to admit, this surprises me somewhat as well. I'd have expected `::` to be the only valid mechanism.

The warning you get in GCC is not about the use of the enum, but about the fact that you use nothing *but* the enum. In such a case, you'd typically write `Foo::number` and avoid instantiating a `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here:

Since the `enum` is technically a type, Foo::number could be treated as a const or static const by the compiler. What would happen if you:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum { number = 42 };

int main()
{
    std::cout << number << endl;
}
```

In this case, `number` *appears* to have been resolved to an immediate, and is valid within both `this->` and `type.` scopes.

As I said, this is just a guess. @LightnessRacesInOrbit has spec quotes. He/She/Insanely-well-informed Turing Machine wins.

Comment: FU, you're not on embedded systems _here_, sunshine!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for removing the comment, but in the context I'm talking about there's no OS, so no return. :) Also, how do you know? The tags say only `C++`.

Comment: Nopes! In C++, the global function `main` _must_ have a return type of `int`. The practical factors surrounding the program's execution are not relevant, even if the OP said he had no OS (which he did not). This also means that all your embedded code is technically ill-formed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've read a lot of your answers and hate to disagree, but at ARM (where I work), IAR, Keil (now owned by ARM), (whatever used to be BSO Tasking), etc..., `void` is a valid return type for `main`. I'm sure it's addressed in CMSIS... :/ It may be ill-formed, but what's the point of returning something to... well, nothing?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as in, for all of the cited tools, it compiles without a warning. Honestly, in that context, a return type other than `void` **should** be an error. Perhaps the spec should be a state machine.

Comment: Regardless, `int` is required. This is simply a fact of the language (`3.6.1/2`). It cannot be disputed. In your environment, the return _value_ would be ignored, but the function must still have an `int` return _type_. It doesn't matter who you work for. :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is. Arguing over the return type in the context of an app that *IS* the OS makes no sense. Citing the spec is *insanely* useful, and a lot of vendors actually bother reading it, but in this specific (probably completely irrelevant) case, it's inappropriate, even if mandated by the spec.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit also, '" the return value would be ignored,"`... Ignored by WHAT?

Comment: Ignored by the OS that doesn't exist. That's why it's ignored. Look, I'm very happy for you that you have a successful career in embedded programming, but in this post you are teaching someone about C++. **The individual has given zero indication that this question is about the embedded world.** So _even_ if it were legal C++ to change `int main` to `void main` (which it is isn't), teaching `void main` is irresponsible!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fair enough. How about we delete the discussion? (You first or it'll look weird.) (Also note that I didn't roll back your edit.)

Comment: I'm happy to leave it! Might be useful for someone.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Excellent point. Beer on me if you're ever in Dallas.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm serious! And frequently at a bar. And in London. And Cambridge. And Munich. :/ Cheers.

Comment: This is not match.com. Get a room you two.

Comment: @Jefffrey Possible duplicate. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts